# Laravel collection get from low to high

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I'm working with a collection.

This is my collection:

```
[
    {
        "km": 38.453608974709326,
        "location": "Store1"
    },
    {
        "km": 72.90179157108496,
        "location": "Store2"
    },
    {
        "km": 185.31643523106044,
        "location": "Store3"
    },
    {
        "km": 182.8661179764287,
        "location": "Store4"
    },
    {
        "km": 199.5931242065379,
        "location": "Store5"
    },
    {
        "km": 117.33173807712892,
        "location": "Store6"
    },
    {
        "km": 156.86414686427264,
        "location": "Store7"
    },
    {
        "km": 148.73811818717547,
        "location": "Store8"
    }
]
```

How do I order this from the lowest km's to the highest? Already tried this but it's not working:

```
$items->sortByDesc(function ($item, $key) {
   return $item['km'];
});
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby) method:

```
$items->sortBy('km')
```